# Could i use OpenXml for editing XPS Files?

Tags: openxml, xps

i guess OpenXml is designed for Office products, but editing XPS files with OpenXml is out of question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not possible.

XPS and Office Open XML only have the container format in common. Which means that the APIs for dealing with the [Open Packaging Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Convention) will be useful; the ones dealing with the underlying file format of Office Open XML will not.

More specifically, XPS uses a subset of XAML, which is totally different (apart from the fact that it uses XML, too).